Should we have a disclaimer?
There is a similar question here from 2012 (Do we want a disclaimer on the sidebar that we cannot offer medical advice?) where it was "accepted" that we don't want a disclaimer on the sidebar, but I am asking should we have one?
If you look at Health.SE, they have a disclaimer which I propose to have ourselves, adjusted to our requirements.

--Edit--
I have just noticed there is a link on educational purposes only.  This leads to the following:

General Disclaimer
The information, advice, links and/or any other materials (“Content”) made available through Health Stack Exchange (the “Site”) are for informational purposes only and are not a substitute for professional medical advice, diagnosis, treatment or consultation. You should contact a qualified licensed medical provider to obtain advice with respect to any important medical issue or problem. Do not disregard or delay in obtaining professional advice based on any Content from the Site. Content may not be complete, correct, or up to date, and some Content may be obtained or provided without proper citation or review. Content made available through the Site does not represent endorsements or recommendations by Stack Exchange or other users. Use of and access to the Site or any Content on the Site, or any of the e-mail, website, social media or other like links contained within the Site, do not create an doctor-patient relationship between those posing or responding to inquiries, or any other users, even if licensed individuals in the corresponding fields are involved in such use. Further, these are not privileged communication, and no right to privacy exists. Any opinions expressed are the opinions of the individual author and may not reflect the opinions of Stack Exchange, or other users. All users of the Site relinquish any or all claims against Stack Exchange, the party providing the Content, and any other users that may arise from reliance on any information obtained from the Site. Reliance on any information appearing on the Site is solely at your own risk.


One issue I would point out is that while I don't know what it is like on the iOS app, the disclaimers like on MedicalSciences.SE are not visible on the StackExchange Android app on mobile phones.
I wasn't aware until today that the disclaimer on MedicalSciences.SE was updated as I predominantly use the mobile phone Android app.
However, I still suggest that we should have a disclaimer, therefore I updated my answer here to reflect the changes on MedicalSciences.SE and alter my suggestion to be similar.

Stack Exchange Inc., and its sites including Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange, is not a medical practice or healthcare provider and does not provide medical advice. You should contact a qualified and licensed practitioner/doctor to obtain the most appropriate advice with respect to any individual medical issue or problem.
Stack Exchange Inc., and its sites including Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange, does not endorse or recommend any healthcare providers that moderate or otherwise contribute to this Site. The information and opinions shared here do not reflect the views of Stack Exchange Inc. and are not provided nor endorsed by Stack Exchange Inc. The content on this site is solely provided by individual community members who are not posting on behalf of Stack Exchange Inc.
Do not share personal medical information, medical history or any other specific details about a person's medical symptoms, condition etc (whether yours or someone you know) on this site or any Stack Exchange site. This is a public Site and all posts on this Site can be seen by anyone and may be shared freely with others.
Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange is for informational exchange only and is not intended as a substitute for individualized diagnosis and treatment by a qualified healthcare provider. Communications on Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange are not privileged/private communications and do not create a patient relationship with the respective medical field.

This way, it is clear from the outset.
The link in the disclaimer could lead to a similar disclaimer to the one on MedicalSciences.SE

We still receive a lot of self-help questions. Although they do get closed rapidly usually, it is worth trying whether such a disclaimer could prevent them altogether.

Health.SE get a lot of self-help questions too.  It would be interesting as I don't know how long they have had the disclaimer up, but even if it has been up a while and not affected the number of self-help questions, at least the site and anyone posting answers is covered by the disclaimer against any possible repercussions.

That is likely already covered by the legal page.

@StevenJeuris - I have been thinking about your comment about the legal page and it could be argued that the legal page you linked is Stack Overflow Orientated and not Stack Exchange wide?

Maybe. My legalize isn't that good. :) That's why I said likely.  But that is a theoretical point. Practically speaking, considering the side bar notice is still worth it.

@StevenJeuris - My legalize may not be any better  I have put this to SE Meta
